# Why does my float print out as 0 even though I input 13.5 for it using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having trouble figuring out why my float variable keeps printing out 0 when I input it as a number.

Code:

```
int num, month, day, year;
float price[10000];


printf("Enter item number: \n");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Enter unit price: \n");
scanf("%f", &price);
printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): \n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

printf("Item\t\tUnit\t\tPurchase\n");
printf("    \t\tPrice\t\tDate\n");
printf("%d      ", num);
printf("$%.2f     ", price); 
printf("      %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year);
return 0;
```

I input 555 for my item number, 13.5 for my price, and 10/24/2010 for my date.
When I did this it printed out that my price was $0.00. It does this for any number I input. Why?

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this:

```
float price[10000];
```

to this:

```
float price;
```

Because you use it as a single variable and not as an array

Comment: This is another example of why one should check the warnings that the compiler reports.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yep :D, most times the compiler warnings/errors are pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried looking up the compiler error online, but I had trouble understanding what exactly was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can not insert array value like this -

```
scanf("%f", &price);
```

Use a for loop to insert values into the array price -

```
for(i=0; i<sizeWhatYouWant; i++){
 scanf("%f", &price[i]);
}
```

Or just change the declaration `float price[10000]` to -

```
float price;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `price` as an array you need to do it this way

```
int num, month, day, year;
float price[10000];


printf("Enter item number: \n");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Enter unit price: \n");
scanf("%f", &price[0]); /* <---- it's not &price it's &price[0] */
printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): \n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

printf("Item\t\tUnit\t\tPurchase\n");
printf("    \t\tPrice\t\tDate\n");
printf("%d      ", num);
printf("$%.2f     ", price[0]); /* <---- it's not price it's price[0] */
printf("      %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year);
return 0;
```

you have to store the value in the first element of the array, and then print the first element too, i.e. `price[0]`.

If you just want to read a single value, then you don't need to declare `price` as an array, so this would be the solution

```
int num, month, day, year;
float price/* [10000] it doesn't need to be an array */;

printf("Enter item number: \n");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Enter unit price: \n");
scanf("%f", &price);
printf("Enter purchase date (mm/dd/yyyy): \n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

printf("Item\t\tUnit\t\tPurchase\n");
printf("    \t\tPrice\t\tDate\n");
printf("%d      ", num);
printf("$%.2f     ", price);
printf("      %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year);
return 0;
```

You was printing the address to the first element of the array instead of the value at that address, and it was being converted to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`, so when you used the `"%f"` specifier, it was printing `0`.

**In both cases**:

To prevent this kind of mistake, you should turn your compilers warnings ON, if using `gcc`

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ${SOURCE_FILES} -o ${OUTPUT_FILE}
```

would do it.

And also, on invalid input, your program will have undefined behavior, you need to check that `scanf()` did actually read the value you instructed it to read, that is achieved by checking the return value from `scanf()` which equals the number of matched items, in your case

```
if (scanf("%d", num) != 1)
    errorInputWasInvalid();
```

since you are requesting `1` item, then `scanf()` has to return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to notice.

1. change `float price[10000];` to `float price;` as you'll be using only a single `float` variable, so you don't need an array.
2. You need to check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure proper input.

Also, as a note, you might want to initialize the local variables, as they are not automatically initialized.